# USRP N210 Connection Issues on Ubuntu 22.04 VirtualBox VM

Tags: software-defined-radio, usrp

I am running into consistent connection issues when trying to run a USRP N210 on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 22.04 VM. I built uhd from source on the ettus page, configured a static IP address in Ubuntu, connected via ethernet port, and successfully found/pinged and received WBFM in GNURadio from my USRP N210. However, after shutting it off and coming back after a few days, I can't get it to ping or for uhd_find_devices to work.

I've tried resetting the IP configuration a few times, and disconnecting/reconnecting the USRP but to no avail. uhd_find_devices and uhd_usrp_probe can't find the device either.

The D & F LEDs are on whenever I plug in the USRP, so I don't believe it's bricked.

Comment: If at all possible, don't use a VM. I've never been able to get good results when using one.

Comment: I was able to find my device with uhd_find_devices --args="addr=192.168.10.2" from MacOS on a different laptop, but only when explicitly stating the IP. It seems like there's some inconsistency with the VM's use of my ethernet port, but I have no idea why.